# Kernel of a zero diagonal, non-negative symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M^n(\mathbb{R})$ a symmetric matrix with zero principal diagonal and with strictly positive off-diagonal entries.

**What is the highest possible dimension of $\,\mathbf{Ker(A)}$?**

When $n=2,3$ it turns out that $A$ is invertible.

If $n=4$ then $A$ can be singular, with $dim(Ker(A))=1$.

I would like to understand if there is a method to study the case of a generic $n$. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Interesting question. Would you please give an example of a singular $A$ of size $4$?

Comment: Sure! Consider $A=[(0,1,1,4),(1,0,1,1),(1,1,0,1),(4,1,1,0)]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum possible nullity $d_n$ is given by $(d_1,d_2,d_3)=(1,0,0)$ (which is evident if you consider $\det(A)$) and $d_n=n-3$ when $n\ge4$.

When $n\ge4$, since the leading principal $3\times3$ submatrix of $A$ is non-singular, it is obvious that $d_n\le n-3$. So, it suffices to construct a feasible $n\times n$ matrix $A_n$ of nullity $n-3$.

In our construction, $A_n$ will be an **integer** matrix and its leading principal $3\times3$ submatrix is
$$
Z=\pmatrix{0&1&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 1&1&0}.
$$
Since $Z$ is non-singular, if we are able to construct an $A_n$ of nullity $n-3$, then the fourth up to the last rows/columns of $A_n$ must be linear combinations of the first three. Consequently, for every $3\le k\le n$, the leading principal $k\times k$ submatrix of $A_n$ is automatically a feasible matrix of size $k$.

It follows that we only need to construct $A_n$ for each $n$ of the form $3m\ge6$. Examples for $n=3m-1$ or $n=3m-2$ can be obtained by deleting rows and columns from $A_{3m}$.

Here is our construction. Let $n=3m\ge6$. By diagonalising $Z$ via congruence over $\mathbb Q$, we see that $Z$ is congruent to $D=\operatorname{diag}(-2,-2,2)$ via an integer matrix:
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&-1&1\\ -1&-1&1\\ 0&1&0},\ P^TZP=D,
\ ZP=\pmatrix{-1&0&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 0&-2&2}.\tag{$\ast$}
$$
Let $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{n-3}>1$ be any $n-3$ distinct positive integers and $v_i=(t_i^2-1,\ 2t_i)^T\in\mathbb Z^2$. Note that $v_i>0$ (because $t_i>1$) and $\|v_i\|=t_i^2+1$ is an integer. This is not surprising, becuase $v_i$ is actually constructed from [Euclid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) for generating Pythagorean triples. We now define
\begin{aligned}
B&=P\pmatrix{v_1&\cdots&v_{n-3}\\
\|v_1\|&\cdots&\|v_{n-3}\|}
\in \mathbb Z^{3\times(n-3)},\\
A_n&=\pmatrix{I_3\\ B^T}Z\pmatrix{I_3&B}=\pmatrix{Z&ZB\\ B^TZ&B^TZB}
\in \mathbb Z^{n\times n}.
\end{aligned}
By construction, $A_n$ always has rank $3$ and hence its nullity is $n-3$. The only question is whether or not $A_n$ has a zero diagonal and positive off-diagonal entries. Let us partition $B$ into $\pmatrix{B_1&\cdots&B_m}$, where each $B_k$ is a square integer matrix of size $3$. Thus we need to show that

1. $B_k^TZB_k$ has the sign pattern of $Z$,
2. $B_k^TZB_l$ is entrywise positive whenever $k\ne l$, and
3. $ZB_l$ is entrywise positive.

It suffices to consider only the case $k=1$ and $l=2$, as all other cases are completely parallel to this one. Since $P^TZP=\operatorname{diag}(-2,-2,2)$ and $ZP$ is given by $(\ast)$, the three conditions above are equivalent to

1. $-\langle v_i,v_i\rangle+\|v_i\|^2=0$ (which is obviously true) and $\|v_i\|\|v_j\|-\langle v_i,v_j\rangle>0$ (which is Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) when $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$ and $i\ne j$,
2. $-\langle v_i,v_j\rangle+\|v_i\|\|v_j\|>0$ (Cauchy-Schwarz inequality again) when $i\in\{1,2,3\},\ j\in\{4,5,6\}$.
3. $-(t_i^2-1)+\|v_i\|>0,\ -2t_i+\|v_i\|>0$ and $(t_i^2-1)+\|v_i\|>0$ (which are true because $t_i^2-1$ and $2t_i$ are two positive coordinates of $v_i$) for each $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

The two Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities above are strict because by construction, no two $v_i$s are parallel to each other. Thus all conditions are satisfied and our proof is complete.

Here is a Matlab/Octave script that you may use for generating an integer matrix $A_n$:

```
n=9; % or any n=3m >= 6

P=[1 -1 1;-1 -1 1;0 1 0];
Z=ones(3,3)-eye(3);
t=2:(n-2);  % any n-3 distinct positive integers > 1 will do
B=P*[t.^2-1;2*t;t.^2+1];  % note: one may further divide B by 2
                          % to get an even nicer form of A,
                          % but don't do this here
A=[Z Z*B; B'*Z B'*Z*B]

% verify that
%   A has a zero diagonal
%   A has positive off-diagonal entries
[max(abs(diag(A))), min(min(A+eye(n)))]
% the result should be [0, some positive integer]

% verify that A_n has n-3 zero eigenvalues
sort(abs(eig(A)))  % all except the last 3 entries
                   % should be close to machine epsilon
rank(A)  % should be 3 in the absence of numerical errors
```

E.g.
$$
A_9=\pmatrix{
0& 1& 1& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2& 2\\
1& 0& 1& 8&18&32&50&72&98\\
1& 1& 0& 2& 8&18&32&50&72\\
2& 8& 2& 0& 4&16&36&64&100\\
2&18& 8& 4& 0& 4&16&36&64\\
2&32&18&16& 4& 0& 4&16&36\\
2&50&32&36&16& 4& 0& 4&16\\
2&72&50&64&36&16& 4& 0& 4\\
2&98&72&100&64&36&16& 4& 0
}.
$$
It happens that with our choices of $t_i\ (=i+1)$ in the Matlab code, all entries of $ZB$ are even. So, if we replace $B$ by $\frac12 B$ in the definition of $A_n$, the outcome will appear nicer and a clear pattern emerges:
$$
A_9=\pmatrix{
0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
1& 0& 1& 4& 9&16&25&36&49\\
1& 1& 0& 1& 4& 9&16&25&36\\
1& 4& 1& 0& 1& 4& 9&16&25\\
1& 9& 4& 1& 0& 1& 4& 9&16\\
1&16& 9& 4& 1& 0& 1& 4& 9\\
1&25&16& 9& 4& 1& 0& 1& 4\\
1&36&25&16& 9& 4& 1& 0& 1\\
1&49&36&25&16& 9& 4& 1& 0
},
$$
and the new $B$ (after division by $2$) in this example is
$$
B=\pmatrix{
 2& 6&12&20&30&42\\
-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6\\
 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7}.
$$

**Edit.** One becomes more absent-minded when growing old. It turned out that I have met a matrix of this kind before and proved that the matrix always has rank $3$! See [Prove a $n \times n $ matrix has rank 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676705/prove-a-n-times-n-matrix-has-rank-3/676729#676729) .

Comment: Very impressive!! The question is completely solved now. One could try to understand if it's possible to construct integer (or algebraic dependent) solutions, but this is another (i guess difficult) story. I just add a curiosity: if $a_{ij}$ are the distances between $n$ distinct points $x_1,\ldots ,x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then the matrix $A$ is non-singular

Comment: @Capublanca I know the trick now. To obtain an integer matrix, we should diagonalise $Z$ by congruence over $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$. See my new edit.

Comment: Yes you are completely right, very nice idea!